# Enable GPU for cryptocurrency mining while running monitor off IGP?

Tags: windows, gpu, cryptography, igp

Users in the cryptocurrency community usually solve this by either:

-Using DVI-A or such to vga adaptor and make a dummy plug with resistors. However, all my hardware run with DVI-D. Vga adaptors don't fit.

-Or supposedly just installing amd drivers, amd sdk and intel IGP drivers + reboot enable both IGP and GPU and they then both support opencl.

My problem is the intel website auto detect doesnt work, manually getting drivers for my i3 3220 IvyBridge all return "computer does not meet requirement" when trying to install them.

Right now what happen is when i boot on IGP as primary, GPU (r9 290) is detected but labeled inactive by miner applications and GPU-Z report OpenCL disabled for the r290 and also for the IGP. (the later is supposed to be enabled if you can install opencl 1.2 for intel IGP but i edit:can't because of same previous error)

W7 64bit, i3 3220 (HD2500), r9 290.

Comment: Most cryptocurrency programs have the capability to through the use of a command line argument which device(s) should be used to mine.  Sounds like you should contact the author of the program for specific help.  Which drivers are you trying to download exactly?  Update your question with this information.

Comment: I know how to specify to which GPU to apply the config and miner program with a simple gpu platorm = 0 or 1 depending if its on the 0 or 1 or 2 slot etc. For intel drivers i'm trying to install whatever drivers for hd2500 and intel open cl, w7 64.

Comment: I would hope this is what you [installed](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/Detail_Desc.aspx?agr=Y&DwnldID=23714&lang=eng)

Comment: It wasn't. I tried to install drivers for intel i3 serie inlc 2500hd support. This works, both IGP and GPU now support openCL, but my hash rate is 60% of what it normally is. What give?

Comment: I would assume thats because of the driver the AMD GPU is using.  It could be any number of things which honestly start to go outside of the scope of this website.

Comment: Why isn't it using installed and properly reported 13.12 that normally give 900khs?

Comment: Why isn't what?  There is a Stackechange website for bitcoins.  Your problem seems to be tuning the software which means you need more a discussion forum or irc channel there is about 20 things I would suggest

Comment: Well if you want to make those suggestion... https://webchat.freenode.net/?channels=bitcoin-cad&uio=d4 i'll be there, if not, i can fiddle with miner settings all over again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am in a similar situation as you, but I got this to work. I have a Core i7 3770K and a Radeon HD7970. Using the latest available graphics drivers from Intel and AMD for Windows 8.1 64-bit, with my BIOS's "IGP Multi-monitor mode" set to "Enabled", I was able to use the IGP as my graphics card by plugging an HDMI HDTV into the motherboard, with nothing plugged into the Radeon, and use the Radeon for compute in the OpenCL application "Diablo Miner" (Java program). It lets you specify the OpenCL device, and both Intel and AMD ICDs were available, so I went ahead and chose AMD.

If you are unable to reproduce this functionality, it could be:

- Your IGP doesn't support multi-monitor mode? I believe this is required. What it should really say is "multi-graphics card mode" from what I can tell, but BIOSes are awful at describing what their options actually **do**.
- Windows 7, using an older revision of the WDDM specification, doesn't support the required infrastructure that's needed for this configuration? In that case, try Windows 8 or 8.1 (8.1 bumps the WDDM revision, so I'd go with 8.1 if I were upgrading from Windows 7.) Also of note is that AMD and Intel maintain *separate* drivers for Windows 7 and Windows 8/8.1, so it could be a Windows7-driver-only bug you are encountering.
- An OpenCL ICD issue? As I recall, older Intel (or was it AMD? I forget now) drivers have a problem with their OpenCL ICD, where the one "errant" ICD will take precedence over and hide all other ICDs from being made available to programs. If you're in this situation, you may have to *completely* uninstall and purge all graphics driver implementations on your system; ensure that no ICD remnants remain; and install fresh (as to what's the proper order of installing the Intel or AMD driver first, I couldn't tell you, as I'm not sure.)

In conclusion, there are various things it could be, but the configuration *should* be possible without having to create a fake VGA plug or anything silly like that. Recent Intel and AMD drivers -- at least on Windows 8/8.1, can't speak for 7 -- should be able to support "compute from anything, render to anything" configurations, where you can choose which device you want to be the *graphics renderer*, and choose which device you want to be the *compute card*. From what I understand, a chip on the motherboard from LucidLogix is supposed to support or enable this, but I don't have their software installed, so I'm not sure if my LucidLogix Virtu MVP device is enabling me to have this configuration, or if it's just built into the platform controller hub of all Z77-series motherboards.

Comment: I checked my Bios and found said option. Called uigp multi-monitor or such. I dont see any different tho. CGWatcher still report GPU INactive, GPU-Z still report OpenCL not supported by 290. 

Maybe i need to find weird intel driver that will let me have OpenCL for 290 even if not on the IGP?

Comment: I rechecked, said option state "enable virtu support". When installing Virtu i get the error "LucidSvc is not running correctly. 
Disabling Virtu MVP 2.0, and exiting." With latest Virtu, amd 13.12. I tried earlier with beta drivers and got same error.

Comment: When you are running Virtu MVP, do you have your monitor plugged into your Radeon, or your motherboard? Make sure you have it plugged into your motherboard.

Comment: Mobo of course. The issue was lack of proper intel drivers. Virtu MVP now work with download link offered by the other helper + the bios option you helped me find. OpenCL work now for both IGP and GPU, however hashrate is suffering terribly, 40% drop. Thoughts?